# Do PDF name objects require capitalization?

Tags: pdf, pdf-parsing

Page 17 of the [PDF 1.7 spec](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) indicates that `/lime#20Green` should produce `Lime Green`. Is this an errata? I see nothing in the spec about capitalizing the first character of a name, and the example just below (`paired#28#29parenthesis`) does not correct capitalization. One of those examples is incorrect, but I'm not confident about which.

[image: page 17 of the PDF 1.7 spec]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do PDF name objects require capitalization?

No. The table entry in ISO 32000-1:2008 you refer to is erroneous. In ISO 32000-2:2017 you find the *Lime Green* line fixed:

[image]